# Is there a way to retrieve the value of object instead of its ID?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

Is there any way to retrieve the object instead of the ID (pk) when using django.core.serializers.serialize.

I have a model named MenuItem with a ManyToManyField releated to a MenuSubItem.

When I execute this code `serializers.serialize('json', MenuItem.objects.all())` I got

```
{'model': 'support.menuitem', 'pk': 2, 'fields': {'type': 2, 'app_label': None, 'label': 'Intranet Administration', 'sub_item': [**3**]}}
```

But what I really wanna get is

```
{'model': 'support.menuitem', 'pk': 2, 'fields': {'type': 2, 'app_label': None, 'label': 'Intranet Administration', 'sub_item': [**objects or objects_attribute**]}}
```

Or if there is a workaround using other libs

Comment: Yes you can serialize relations: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, It's actually a very common thing to do in APIs that there's an article in the docs about it, have a look at [DRF serializer relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/), This is called a nested serialization, When you want to serializer something that has another something serializable in it, DRF is very fun to learn, There's also JustDjango on YouTube who's explaining some basics to work with DRF

Your code should look look

```
class mySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    Meta:
        model = myModelThatIwantToNest
        fields = ['....']

class myOtherSerializer(serializers.ModeSerializer):
    myModelThatIwantToNest = mySerializer();
    Meta:
        model = myOtherModel
        fields = ['myModelThatIwantToNest', '...']
```